# passing attributes to ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code for generate `a` tags:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var schedule in scheduleGroup)
    {
        <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(string.Format("{0:HH\\:mm}", schedule.RecurrenceStart), "EventOverview", "BaseEvent", new { id = schedule.BaseEvent.OID, type = schedule.BaseEvent.XPObjectType}, new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                   {"session", schedule.SessionId},
                   {"hall",schedule.HallId},
                   {"client",schedule.BasePlace.PremieraClientId}                                                                       
                })
    } 
</ul>
```

But, html attributes shows not correctly in the `a` tag . This is generated markup:

```
<a href="/Film/Event/36" values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" count="3" comparer="System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[System.String]">20:15</a>
```

Where is a error?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I want the following:

```
<a client="1" hall="1" session="15" href="/BaseEvent/EventOverview?id=36&type=Film"> 20:15 </a>
```

Comment: Can you show us what result you want it to be?

Comment: I am supposing he wants to generate an action link with the session, hall and client variables set -> <a href="/Film/Event/36?Session=SessionId&hall=hallId&client=clientId>20:15</a> -> but it is unclear if that is the intention

Comment: @Tommy: sorry for delay answer. I updated question. See, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
@Html.ActionLink(string.Format("{0:HH\\:mm}", schedule.RecurrenceStart), "EventOverview", "BaseEvent", 
                new { id = schedule.BaseEvent.OID, type = schedule.BaseEvent.XPObjectType},
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                                {
                                   {"session", schedule.SessionId},
                                   {"hall",schedule.HallId},
                                   {"client",schedule.BasePlace.PremieraClientId}                                                                       
                                })
```

If your intention is to generate a link as @Tommy said that is 'session', 'hall', 'schedule' are as queryStirng parameter, then the code should be:

```
@Html.ActionLink(string.Format("{0:HH\\:mm}", "schedule.RecurrenceStart"), "EventOverview", "BaseEvent",
        new { id = schedule.BaseEvent.OID, type = schedule.BaseEvent.XPObjectType, 
                session= schedule.SessionId, hall =schedule.HallId,  client =schedule.BasePlace.PremieraClientId},
        null)
```

Otherwise if you want the 'session', 'hall', 'schedule' as html attributes(
according to your given code) , there are two matching [ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) method signatures:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

And

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

You have to choose one of them. That is send both parameters 'routeValues' and 'htmlAttributes' as anonymous object (1st one) or as typed object, 'RouteValueDictionary' for 'routeValues' and '`IDictionary<string, Object>`' for 'htmlAttributes'. Your given code matched the 1st one, that is why the 'htmlAttributes' of type `IDictionary<string, Object>` treat as Object and generating the incorrect tag.

Correct code should be:

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: string.Format("{0:HH\\:mm}", "schedule.RecurrenceStart"), actionName: "EventOverview", controllerName: "BaseEvent",
        routeValues: new { id = schedule.BaseEvent.OID, type = schedule.BaseEvent.XPObjectType },
        htmlAttributes: new
        {
            session = schedule.SessionId,
            hall = schedule.HallId,
            client = schedule.BasePlace.PremieraClientId
        } )
```

Or

```
@Html.ActionLink(string.Format("{0:HH\\:mm}", "schedule.RecurrenceStart"), "EventOverview", "BaseEvent",

        new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = schedule.BaseEvent.OID, type = schedule.BaseEvent.XPObjectType }),

        new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"session", schedule.SessionId},
                {"hall", schedule.HallId},
                {"client", schedule.BasePlace.PremieraClientId}                                                                       
            })
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. This is what I need to (second option). Thanks.